# Stuck with getJson .then() function and this.store.find

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have the following ApplicationController:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    // the initial value of the `search` property
    query: '',

    actions: {
        searchQuery: function () {
            // the current value of the text field
            var query = this.get('search');

            // numeric search
            if (parseInt(query) > 0) {
                this.transitionToRoute('article', this.store.find('article', query)); // works
            }
            // string search
            else {
                // search database for the search keyword
                jQuery.getJSON("/search/article/" + query + "").then(function(response){
                    if(parseInt(response.id) > 0){
                        console.log(response.id); // 1 when searching a specific value

                    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined     
                    this.transitionToRoute('article', this.store.find('article', response.id)); 
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
});
```

I am stuck on the second `this.transitionToRoute` call. It is in the same controller. However the last one returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined`.

Has it to do with the getJSON method? I have tried to call the transition outside the getJSON call. But then the promise will not work.

Has anyone experience with this kind of call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` changes scope inside of the `then`, set a reference to `this` outside of the then and use that reference inside of the then (such as I did below with `self`)

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    // the initial value of the `search` property
    query: '',

    actions: {
        searchQuery: function () {
            var self = this;
            // the current value of the text field
            var query = this.get('search');

            // numeric search
            if (parseInt(query) > 0) {
                this.transitionToRoute('article', this.store.find('article', query)); // works
            }
            // string search
            else {
                // search database for the search keyword
                jQuery.getJSON("/search/article/" + query + "").then(function(response){
                    if(parseInt(response.id) > 0){
                        console.log(response.id); // 1 when searching a specific value

                    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined     
                    self.transitionToRoute('article', self.store.find('article', response.id)); 
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! While I was editing my question for more information you already typed the answer! 
However I call my question the 17-o'clock-programming-black-out.

Comment: I know the feeling, it happens to all of us.